# Measure length in UV EDITOR

Tags: uv, measurement

Is there a way to have something like Edge length but for UV editor ? I am doing texturing manually in photoshop, and the workflow is that I export the UV layout, open it in photoshop and then I know the 'areas' that I need to work on. However, it would be extremely careful if I could know the size of a resized island displayed in pixels directly in the UV editor so that I can quickly update that in photoshop.

Posting a picture to explain what I mean:
[image]

As you can see on the right side with Edge Length displayed, I can see the faces are 200cm X 200cm.
When unwrapped, let's say I want to have them different sizes depending on how I texture them. I would love to be able to see after I scale them up or down, the size of the face in pixels.

Is there any way or maybe an addon to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't export UV layout suitable for you?

Comment: That's my current workflow. I want to be faster, because if I want to texture only one face, let's say a rectangle, it's just too slow to export all of it, import it in photoshop etc, instead of just having the right dimensions and doing it directly in PS. To be clear, I can get that number from Texel Density if I open up calculator lol, but it's again extra steps that are unnecessary.